# Как получить значение переменной из while True

Tags: python, криптография

Мне надо получать значение hash раз в 600 секунд из while True, чтобы потом запускать функцию encrypt_decrypt сколько угодно (не раз в 600 секунд). Прошу прощения за такой странный код, просто на улицу давно не выходил) Если нужны уточнения - спрашивайте.

```
def listen():
    while True:
        yield hash_generate.generator()
        time.sleep(600)


def encrypt_decrypt():
        s = crypter.encrypt(key=hash, plaintext="Text")
        crypter.decrypt(key=hash, ciphertext=s)


for i in listen():
    hash = hash_generate.hashvalue2
    print(hash_generate.hashvalue2)
    encrypt_decrypt()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [52]: import time

In [53]: import random

In [54]: def ensure_periodic_value(interval):
    ...:     def wrapper(func):
    ...:         def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:             if time.monotonic() - getattr(func, "ttl", interval) >= interval:
    ...:                 func.periodic_value = random.randint(1, 100)
    ...:                 func.ttl = time.monotonic()
    ...:             return func(func.periodic_value)
    ...:         return inner
    ...:     return wrapper
    ...:

In [55]: @ensure_periodic_value(interval=5)
    ...: def func(random_value):
    ...:     print(f"Random value is: {random_value}")
    ...:

In [56]: while True:
    ...:     func()
    ...:     time.sleep(5)
    ...:
```

Каждые `interval` секунд в функцию `func` будет передано рандомное число, вывод:

```
Random value is: 80
Random value is: 84
Random value is: 34
```

Вместо 5 секунд передайте 600, вместо рандома - ваш хэш.

Comment: Ответ помог, только как вставить функцию encrypt_decrypt? Как я понимаю нужно переменную random_value обьявить глобальной.

Comment: @user353189 над функцией `encrypt_decrypt ` поставьте декоратор, в принимайте в аргумент значение

Comment: В ответе `func` всего лишь пример, там должна быть Ваша функция

Comment: Отлично, спасибо вам!